# How to set variable in Tkinter in checkbox in newly created window

Tags: python, python-2.7, checkbox, tkinter

Everything is good if I'm in root window but I can't set variable in newly created window. It always gives me default empty checkbox. I have one more question and that is how can I save chosen options so when I open options(settings) window again same options will be checked or unchecked.

```
from Tkinter import *

# TKINTER CODE ######################################################################## #

root = Tk()
root.title('window')
Label(text='input').grid(row=0, sticky=W, padx=10, pady=10)

entry = Entry(root, width=50)
entry.grid(row=1, sticky=W+E, padx=10, pady=10)
entry.insert(0, "input")

text = Text(root, width=80, state=DISABLED)
text.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, padx=0, pady=0)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=N+S+W+E)
scrollbar.config(command=text.yview)

# Settings window


def open_settings():
    settings_win = Toplevel(root)
    settings_win.title('Settings')
    settings_win.geometry('300x300')
    settings_win.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
    settings_win_button.config(state='disable')

    def close_settings_window():
        settings_win.destroy()
        settings_win_button.config(state='normal')

    # options to choose from
    option_var1 = IntVar()
    # Make default position to be checked
    option_var1.set(1)

    option_var2 = IntVar()

    option1 = Checkbutton(settings_win, text="option1", variable=option_var1)
    option1.grid(row=0, column=0)

    option2 = Checkbutton(settings_win, text="option2", variable=option_var2)
    option2.grid(row=1, column=0)

    quit_settings_button = Button(settings_win, text='Save', command=close_settings_window)
    quit_settings_button.grid(row=10, column=0)

    settings_win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", close_settings_window)

settings_win_button = Button(root, text='Options', command=open_settings)
settings_win_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

# Menu Bar ############################################################################ #
menubar = Menu(root)

# create a pulldown menu, and add it to the menu bar
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
# filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)

# display the menu
root.config(menu=menubar)

# End ################################################################################# #

root.mainloop()
```

I want option1 in newly created window to be checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add the line `root.wait_window(settings_win)` after your `settings_win.protocol...` line:

```
settings_win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", close_settings_window)
root.wait_window(settings_win)
```

I think what's happening is the running event loop is still trying to process the `root` window, so it is not actively updating the `Toplevel`. What `wait_window` will do is [create a local event loop](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm). The `root` will now wait for the `Toplevel` to be destroyed to continue processing. This forces the `Toplevel` to constantly update, which means the default value of `option1` will be checked.

You will need to store the value of `option_var1` and `option_var2` somewhere, however. Currently, they are recreated every time you open the option window, which means they always take their default values.

Hopefully this helps you solve your problem.

Comment: Works great. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

the reason option1 starts unchecked despite setting the variable to 1 is because `option_var1` is a local variable to the `open_settings` function, once the function finishes `option_var1` is deleted and the check boxes lose their reference.  You can fix this simply by adding a global statement:

```
def open_settings():
    global option_var1,option_var2
    ....
```

Although any case that the option_var1 keeps a reference after creation (which is needed to do anything with the settings anyway) will also fix the reference issue.

Comment: Thanks for answer. When possible I'd like to avoid using global variables,

Comment: So do I, but any way you plan on holding onto the control variable to use it in your program will work but if you are not at that stage of your project then the global statement would work while under development.